# Passing Audio Files To Celery Task

Tags: django, file-upload, celery

I have a music uploading app and believe that it would be smart to pass the files to a celery task to handle uploading.  However, when attempting to pass the files, as I will show in my code below, I get a message stating that they are not JSON serializable.  What would be the correct way to handle this operation?

Everything below uploaded_songs in .views.py is my current code that successfully uploads the audio tracks.  It doesn't, however, utilize celery yet.

.task.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from Beyond_April_Base_Backend.celery import app
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@app.task
def upload_songs(songs, user_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        print('user and songs')
        print(user)
        print(songs)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        logging.warning("Tried to find non-exisiting user '%s'" % user_id)
```

.views.py

```
class ConcertUploadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        track_files = request.FILES.getlist('files')
        current_user = self.request.user
        upload_songs.delay(track_files, current_user.pk)
        try:
            selected_band = Band.objects.get(name=request.data['band'])
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('band not received from form')
            selected_band = Band.objects.get(name='Band')
        venue_name = request.data['venue']
        concert_date_str = request.data['concertDate']
        concert_date_split = concert_date_str.split('(')[0]
        concert_date = datetime.strptime(concert_date_split, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z ')
        concert_city = request.data['city']
        concert_state = request.data['state']
        concert_country = request.data['country']

        new_concert = Concert(
            venue=venue_name,
            date=concert_date,
            city=concert_city,
            state=concert_state,
            country=concert_country,
            band=selected_band,
            user=current_user,
        )
        new_concert.save()
    
        i = 0
        for song in track_files:
            audio_metadata = music_tag.load_file(track_files[i].temporary_file_path())
            temp_path = song.temporary_file_path
            song_title = str(audio_metadata['title'])
            audio_file_instance = Song(
                title=song_title,
                concert=new_concert,
                user=current_user,
                concert_order = i + 1,
                audio_file = track_files[i],
            )
            audio_file_instance.save()
            i += 1
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a celery task, it serializes the arguments so that it can store the message in the queue backend (RabbitMQ, Redis, etc). The default serializer is JSON, and a binary file is not JSON-serializable. See [celery's serialization docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#serializers) for more info.

You could base64 encode the binary file to text, but you shouldn't: it will increase the size of the data, and you'll be passing around potentially very large messages. With lots of large messages, you could run out of memory/space in your backend, and it will make it hard to inspect or log messages.

Instead, you should store the binary file somewhere, and pass a reference (filename, S3 URL, database key, etc) to the task. The task can then load the file, do what it needs to, and delete the original (if appropriate).

Comment: But IMO if I wanna save the file the whole point of using celery goes under a big question. It is a negative thing for my use case. I am uploading huge big files. If I save them user have to wait for long time.